# Phoenix Canarienses going brown and dying

Tags: plant-health

Hope you can help. I have a beautiful Phoenix Canarienses that was very healthy till this summer and then suddenly is going brown and slowly dying but I have no idea what is the reason. I have attached some pics so you can have a look.

I came back after a one month trip and found one leaf (new born leaf) down the floor completely dry and dead. So I water it during the summer and gave a fertiliser as well. But no matter what I do, all the other leaves are turning brown. I am afraid the plant is not going to survive the winter in London, while it did last year greatly. Also, it is weird because as you maybe can see from the pic, new leaves are there but they look damaged and dry as well! Please help !!!!

Chiara [image]

Comment: During that one month trip, did the plant get any water?

Comment: London, UK? Is there drainage in that pot and how long's it been in the same pot?

Comment: I agree with bamboo, possible root rot could be a cause and the plane should be reported into a similar size pot with drainage